# Trading View Typescript Emitted no output

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, tradingview-api

I am using vuejs + nuxtjs and I integrate trading view to my project. When i try to import the charting_library.min.d.ts in the vue component it return error.

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for [[charting_library.min.d.ts file]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying `tsconfig.json` could solve this issue.

Turn off emit outputs by adding:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "noEmit": false
}
```

If you need this feature, try to add:

```
"exclude": [
  "node_modules"
]
```